# Using 2 thread to write in 2 text file with C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I want to write a C# console application program
that write in two text file with using two thread.
The two files contain all numbers from 1 to 2000 but There is no number is repeated twice in 2 files 
as the first file (123......), the second (456.....)

thanks

Comment: You'll need to show your code, what your out put is, and what you're expecting.

Comment: Have you even tried to do your Homework?

Comment: What part are you having trouble with? Show us what you've tried, and tell us where it's not working as you expected.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried, you must have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### you need to break the data into chunks. There are several algorithms for this, but I will demonstrate with "odd and even".

This help you?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            //odd
            Thread _th1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate
            {
                StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText("thread1.txt");
                for (int i = 0; i <= 2000; i=i+2)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("th1:" + i.ToString());
                    sw.Write(i.ToString()+";");    
                }
                sw.Close();
            }));

            //even
            Thread _th2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate
            {
                StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText("thread2.txt");
                for (int i = 1; i <= 2000; i = i + 2)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("th2:" + i.ToString());
                    sw.Write(i.ToString()+";");
                }
                sw.Close();
            }));

            _th1.Start();
            _th2.Start();

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this run program does't write any thing in the files
the output is th1:number

Comment: thread1.txt writed with 0;2;4;6...2000
thread2.txt writed with 1;3;5;7...1999

see this files in application running current folder